# обработка и вывод на превью в Camera2 api android

Tags: android, android-camera

В новом API для работы с камерой можно установить сразу несколько получателей выходного потока с камеры, в формате `List<Surface>`. Мне надо покадрово обработать поток с камеры, для этого я в качестве получателя планирую использовать ImageReader.
Мне не понятно как после всех манипуляций в методе `OnImageAvailableListener.onImageAvailable()` я должен увидить изменения на экране?

Answer (score 2):

Итак, учитывая что в качестве получателей изображения передаются `Surface` от разных объектов то следует поступить иным способом - после обработки изображения в `OnImageAvailableListener.onImageAvailable()` направить результат на `Surface` того `View` который отвечает за предпросмотр.
Изначально я использовал формат YUV_420_888

```
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(w, h, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
```

т.к. он наиболее быстрый, однако привести его к виду подходящему для редактирования оказалась не менее творческая задача (однозначно обработка трех каналов в цикле не позволит накладывать изменения в реальном времени). Решил использовать `ImageFormat.JPEG` . Очень полезную информацию нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673127/android-imagereader-acquirelatestimage-returns-invalid-jpg). Однако использование `ImageFormat.JPEG` слишком медленно, а следуя из одного из ответов по вышеуказанной ссылке другие форматы, даже если и будут конвертироваться в `Bitmap` относительно быстро, могут не поддерживаться некоторыми устройствами.

На текущий момент описанный мной способ решения поставленной задачи считаю не оптимальным. Возможно на нижеприведенной схеме можно найти другие точки вхождения для перехвата и обработки изображения, однако я решил искать альтернативы.

[image: Схема Camera2 API]

Для моих целей подходит OpenCV. Несмотря на то что библиотека написана на С++, есть готовое решение в Java обертке для Android.